# How do i validate and give list of options after first wrong attempt in FormFlow Bot Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, botframework

I am trying to build a bot using bot framework where i want to take string from user for a department name using FormFlow and if user enters wrong department name, I want to validate and give back a list of choices to choose from

DepartmentName string:

```
[Prompt("What is your department name? {||}")]
 public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
```

Deaprtment name field is as following:

```
.Field(nameof(DepartmentName),

            validate: async (state, response) =>
            {
                var value = (string)response;
                var result = new ValidateResult() { IsValid = false, Feedback = "Department name is not valid"};
                if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(Department)).Any(x => x.ToLower() == value))
                {
                    result.IsValid = true;
                    result.Feedback = null;
                    result.Value = value;
                }
                return result;
            })
```

Department enum is as following:

```
public enum Department
{
    hr = 1,
    sales,
    marketing,
    development,
    qm
}
```

How can i prompt  user with list of departments in enum if first attempt goes wrong? Thnaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you can just add the options to the end of the Feedback:

```
.Field(nameof(DepartmentName),
validate: (state, response) =>
{
    var value = (string)response;
    string[] departments = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Department)).ToArray();
    var feedback = $"Department name is not valid. Options:\n\n {String.Join("\n\n", departments)}";

    var result = new ValidateResult() { IsValid = false,                                            
                                        Feedback = feedback  };

    if (departments.Any(x => x.ToLower() == value))
    {
        result.IsValid = true;
        result.Feedback = null;
        result.Value = value;
    }
    return Task.FromResult<ValidateResult>(result);
});
```

2) you can use the Choice class (normally for disambiguation):

```
.Field(nameof(DepartmentName),
    validate: (state, response) =>
    {
        var value = (string)response;
        string[] departments = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Department)).ToArray();

        IEnumerable<Choice> choices = departments.Select(d => new Choice()
                {
                    Description = new DescribeAttribute(d, null, null, null, null),
                    Terms = new TermsAttribute() { Alternatives = new[] { d } },
                    Value = d
                }).ToArray();

        var result = new ValidateResult()
        {
            IsValid = false,
            Choices = choices,
            Feedback = "Department name is not valid."
        };

        if (departments.Any(x => x.ToLower() == value))
        {
            result.IsValid = true;
            result.Feedback = null;
            result.Value = value;
        }
        return Task.FromResult<ValidateResult>(result);
    });
```